# How to run a script after Pyramid's transaction manager has returned

Tags: pyramid

How can I run myscript.py after the transaction manager has returned. Additionally, I would prefer if the script was not blocking.

In my view, I am receiving a file from a POST. Since I'm creating the file with `repoze.filesafe`'s `create_file()`, it keeps the file in a temporary location until the transaction manager returns. The file only exists on the harddisk in its correct path after transaction manager has returned without an error.

Therefore, I need to run my script after the transaction manager has returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a hook to be run after commit via the [`transaction` package](http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/transactions.html#after-commit-hooks). Register one in your view:

```
import transaction


def your_after_commit(success, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None):
    if success:
        print "Transaction commit succeeded"
    else:
        print "Transaction commit failed"


def someview(request):
    current_transaction = transaction.get()
    current_transaction.addAfterCommitHook(your_after_commit, args=(1, 2), kws={kwarg1='foo', kwargs2='bar'})
```

This still runs your script in the context of the current request (e.g. the request does not complete until your script returns). If you need a full asynchronous setup, you'll need to move to a proper asynchronous solution such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). You would not use that with a transaction hook; just register a task to be run with Celery instead.

Comment: Just so we're clear, the commit hook runs in the same thread as the request. If your transaction is committed and then your script fails, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: The only way I can avoid that is to know the temporary file's path/name set by `create_file`. What's the usual way to protect against @MichaelMerickel's warning?

Comment: You could use a async setup such as Celery to execute tasks at a time after the transaction has comitted.

Comment: Why does that avoid problems caused by the script failing?

Comment: Because it won't affect your clients. If your script fails during the request then the transaction is committed yet the client receives an error page.

Comment: @Raj: The failure is then isolated from the request itself.